# How to get ParentfolderId and ParentFolderName in Google

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api

Forexample i have a file that has a id= 0B5DVdBv12vz_QTJSM1QtMkZPQ1k and i want to get the name and id of its parent folder. Is there any function for that in Javascript?

Comment: File.get send it your id.   then look at the response you will find parents which is a https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/parents#resource

Comment: @ DaImTo I did use parents field, but it did not give the information of parent. It gives only a empty bracket.

Comment: show your code.  Remember that files can have from zero to many parents